# Click event not working after interation

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a chart with a click event, it works well until I click on the label (group/fixed labels). After this the event doesn't work anymore.

I've attached this event to my page:

```
d3.selectAll("rect.nv-bar").on("click", function (d) {
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

Here's a fiddle with the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/ygQZW/

**Am I doing something wrong or it's some kind of bug?**

-- **UPDATE** --

The solution that @explunit posted solved 50% of my problem. Now, when I click on the color labels for hide/show the bars, the click effect stops on the bar previously hidden.

Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ygQZW/1/

**How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by myself.

Instead of using `d3.selectall` I used the jQuery selector and I've selected the parent tag. In the parent tag I've attached a hover event which start another one on the children nodes.

By doing this, when the bars are hidden and then showed again, the parent tag event start the click events again.

My new code:

```
$(".nv-group").on("hover", function(d) {
    $(".nv-bar").off("click"); // Remove previous events, if have
    $(".nv-bar").on("click", function(d) {
        alert("Clicked!");
    });
});
```

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ygQZW/4/

I think that this isn't the best and graceful solution, if someone have a better solution please post it!

Comment: Hey, would you mind completing this jsfiddle in order to show what you display in «detalhamento» ? Do you display a second graph ? I wrote a bad directive, because after one display the graph at the top thinks he is the one of above.

Comment: @Ehvince I don't understand what you want, but in my application I have two scenarios: in the first I'll redirect to another page on click passing the X axis value as parameter. In the second scenario I'll open a Twitter's Bootstrap modal, showing another chart based on the X axis.

Answer (score 1):

If you namespace your click handler then it will not be overwritten by whatever else NVD3 is doing with events as the graph changes:

```
d3.selectAll("rect.nv-bar").on("click.mine", function (d) {
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

From the [API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-on):

> To register multiple listeners for the same event type, the type may be followed by an optional namespace, such as "click.foo" and "click.bar".